# How to override onCreate or onPause methods of a new Intent

Tags: android, android-intent

I am creating a new intent like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
```

And I want to override its onCreate or onPause methods. How can I do it?

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An Intent is compared to Intent filters as they're definded in the Apps Manifest's. If an Intent filter matches, the corresponding Activity or Service is started.
So an Intent itself has no `onCreate` or `onPause` method.

The best you can do is, to create an Activity with the required behavior, put a SurfaceView with Camera logic in it and start it with your own intent.

Here is the link to Androids [guide to camera apps](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html). It's not too difficult to write the necessary Activity.

Answer (score 0):

If you start a new `intent` you ask the system to call any activty that is registered for this  action/namespaces. If you yourself register this in your app you can of course change the onCreate() or onPause(), but usually you have no possibility to change how the intent is handled by the other app. Furthermore I do not get your use-case, if you maybe make clear what you want to do SO could be more of assitence.

Comment: I am trying to change the systemUIVisibility of the camera view as soon as it is called, that is why I wanted to override the onCreate method.

Comment: Well thats not possible, you cannot change the code of foreign activities. If you want a custom camera view you have to implement it yourself.